# UITableview doesn't work on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am trying to compile open source dictionary located at https://github.com/rannger/Dictionary It compiles and runs perfectly on both `iPhone` and `iPad` if I compile as `iPhone` application. However if I compile as universal app table is not populated with data from database. I compiled with `Xcode 6` and `iOS 8.1 SDK`. First I thought it is due to `SearchDisplayBar` deprecated, but even compiling with `Xcode 5.1.1` and `iOS 7.1` SK still same result.

Here is the code responsible for populating data.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.title=@"Index";
    _objects = @[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X",@"Y",@"Z"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    UISearchBar* searchBar=[[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 44+20)];
    searchBar.delegate=self;
    searchBar.barTintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    item=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks
                                                                        target:self
                                                                        action:@selector(favs)];

    searchDisplayController=[[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate=self;
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource=self;
    searchDisplayController.delegate=self;
    searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar=YES;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
    searchResult=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100];
    [self setFavBtn];
}
//Selecting item from the table

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    if (tableView==self.tableView) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSArray *list=[RLWord wordByFirstChar:_objects[indexPath.row]];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [searchResult removeAllObjects];
                [searchResult addObjectsFromArray:list];
                self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text=_objects[indexPath.row];
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=nil;
                [searchDisplayController setActive:YES];
            });
        });
    }
    else
    {
        RLWord* word=[searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        RLDetailViewController* ctrl=[[RLDetailViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        ctrl.detail=word;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:ctrl animated:YES];
        [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO];
        [self setFavBtn];
    }

}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{

    [searchResult removeAllObjects];
    if (IsStringWithAnyText(searchText)) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSArray *list=[RLWord wordByFirstChar:searchText];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [searchResult addObjectsFromArray:list];
                [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
            });
        });
    }
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];

}
```

If I create the view inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and add items again I can see the words starting with selected letter

```
 RLWordsTableViewController* ctrl=[[RLWordsTableViewController alloc] init]; 
 ctrl.words=list;
 [ctrl reload];
```

I will really appreciate your help because I can't find the reason why it works when it is compiled as `iPhone` application but doesn't work when it is compiled as Universal app.

Comment: What exactly is wrong when you compile as universal app? It does compile, but does not display the contents?

Comment: if I compile as universal app, It compiles but when I click any letter it doesn't show the entries on iPad but works on iPhone. If i compile as iPhone app it works both on iPhone and iPad(small screen).